# Is there a way to write to a file in online CMS from a local C++ program?

Tags: c++, leaflet, web-development-server

I created a very customized leaflet map on a Bitrix website (they forced me to, not my choice). Now other coworkers who are basically "afraid" of code need to be able to add markers to that. I already created a C++ program where they can simply enter all the details they want (what category, whats the popupcontent etc.) and it spits out the geoJSON code for the marker for them to copy and paste into the website.

To make it even more easy for them I am wondering if there is a way to basically have my program connect to the internet, go to the backend of my website and, after asking for login, adds the code to the respective .js file that contains only the marker code.

I have been googling the problem but unfortunately couldnt find any other related posts.

Comment: What access do you have to your server? SSH, FTP, ...?

Comment: apparently it is a fully cloud based website and after just talking to the technical support they told me I can not access the server remotely. My idea was to let a program basically go through the same steps I would do it manually, like "open the browser, go the website, provide login, open that file, write to it, logout". But I guess I am thinking to simple here?

Comment: "It's a nice idea," yes, but I find myself wondering if it's worth doing.  If you *did* do it, I'd probably look at some kind of "shell script" that invokes your C++ program as-is, then does something with the output *e.g.* using tools like Curl.  You probably have other programming languages on-hand which would be easier to apply to this task, and easier to change.

Comment: You could probably try to emulate that behaviour by copying the requests that get sent when you do this manually, but this will break whenever the cloud company changes anything. As long as they don't offer a web API of some kind, this won't work reliably.

Comment: I agree with @MikeRobinson that C++ would not be the language of choice for web automation of this scale. Python and other scripting languages have libraries that are better suited for this purpose.

Comment: @Nab If your website is hosted with bitrix24.com, they expose a REST API, but I don't know how much of that is publicly usable and if you can do with it, what you need to do. See https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/landing/index.php

Comment: I did think so too and I am way more familiar with python than C++, I mainly though to use C++ because I need the program to be executable from my coworkers computers withouth much further ado. The big benefit from C++ was just to directly create windows executable .exe programs...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally found the I guess easiest way, I will force my colleagues to install python and write a little thingy to concatenate the code and upload it using Selenium. Thanks for your help guys!